# How can I add a timer to a game to make the game reset when the timer reaches 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, turtle-graphics

I'm making a game where there is a chaser and a runner (Bob and Phil) on a screen. It's pretty much like tag. As of right now, if the chaser collides with the runner, the game resets and the players move back their original positions. I want to add a timer so that when the timer reaches 0, the game will reset.

I thought about having a variable called 'time', and have it equal to 60. I would then make the variable subtract by 1 every second with time -= 1 and the time.sleep function. The problem is that the time.sleep function will stop the ENTIRE program. Is there any way to implement a timer in my game without running into the previously mentioned problems?

```
import turtle
import math

# Distance formula for collision checking
def isCollision(t1, t2):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(t1.xcor()-t2.xcor(),2)+math.pow(t1.ycor()-t2.ycor(),2))
    if distance < 30:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Makes the wn that the game is played on
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width = 900, height = 900)
wn.tracer()

# Runs the actual game when space is pressed, see around end of code to understand
def game():
        start.clear()
        runner = "omright.gif"
        chaser = "pilav angry.gif"
        wn.addshape(chaser)
        wn.addshape(runner)

        #Designs the 4 sides of the game
        border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
        border_pen.speed(0)
        border_pen.color("white")
        border_pen.penup()
        border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
        border_pen.pendown()
        border_pen.pensize(3)
        for side in range(4):
            border_pen.fd(600)
            border_pen.lt(90)
        border_pen.hideturtle()

        title = turtle.Turtle()
        title.speed(0)
        title.color("white")
        title.penup()
        title.setpos(0, 325)
        title.write("THE TAG GAME BY OM", False, align = 'center', font=('Impact', 55, 'normal'))
        title.setpos(370, 315)
        title.write("Patent Pending", False, align = 'center', font=('Calibri', 11, 'normal'))
        title.setpos(370, -335)
        title.write("Not Really Pending", False, align = 'center', font=('Calibri', 11, 'normal'))
        title.hideturtle()

        # First turtle (basically an object that can be manipulated)
        bob = turtle.Turtle()
        bob.speed(0)
        bob.color("blue")
        bob.penup()
        bob.setpos(-50, 0)
        bob.seth(0)
        bob.shape(chaser)


        # Function to move first turtle (bob)
        def fd():
            bob.seth(90)
            bob.fd(20)
            # Border Checking
            if bob.xcor() > 280:
                bob.setx(280)
            if bob.ycor() > 280:
                bob.sety(280)

            if bob.xcor() < -280:
                bob.setx(-280)
            if bob.ycor() < -280:
                bob.sety(-280)
            # Checks for collision with enemy player
            if isCollision(bob, phil):
                # If there is collision, resets players'
                bob.setposition(-50, 0)
                phil.setposition(50, 0)
                bob.seth(0)
                phil.seth(180)

        # Moves right (90 degrees)
        def right():
            bob.seth(0)
            bob.fd(20)
            # Border Checking
            if bob.xcor() > 280:
                bob.setx(280)
            if bob.ycor() > 280:
                bob.sety(280)

            if bob.xcor() < -280:
                bob.setx(-280)
            if bob.ycor() < -280:
                bob.sety(-280)
            # Checks for collision with enemy player
            if isCollision(bob, phil):
                # If there is collision, resets players'
                bob.setposition(-50, 0)
                phil.setposition(50, 0)
                bob.seth(0)
                phil.seth(180)

        # Moves left (90 degrees)
        def left():
            bob.seth(180)
            bob.fd(20)
            # Border Checking
            if bob.xcor() > 280:
                bob.setx(280)
            if bob.ycor() > 280:
                bob.sety(280)

            if bob.xcor() < -280:
                bob.setx(-280)
            if bob.ycor() < -280:
                bob.sety(-280)
            # Checks for collision with enemy player
            if isCollision(bob, phil):
                # If there is collision, resets players'
                bob.setposition(-50, 0)
                phil.setposition(50, 0)
                bob.seth(0)
                phil.seth(180)
        def down():
            bob.seth(270)
            bob.fd(20)
            # Border Checking
            if bob.xcor() > 280:
                bob.setx(280)
            if bob.ycor() > 280:
                bob.sety(280)
                phil.seth(180)

            if bob.xcor() < -280:
                bob.setx(-280)
            if bob.ycor() <- 280:
                bob.sety(-280)
            # Checks for collision with enemy player
            if isCollision(bob, phil):
                # If there is collision, resets players'
                bob.setposition(-50, 0)
                phil.setposition(50, 0)
                bob.seth(0)
                phil.seth(180)

        # Logs keys and outputs function
        wn.listen()
        wn.onkey(left, "Left")
        wn.onkey(fd, "Up")
        wn.onkey(right, "Right")
        wn.onkey(down, "Down")

        # Second turtle
        phil = turtle.Turtle()
        phil.speed(0)
        phil.penup()
        phil.shape("triangle")
        phil.color("red")
        phil.setpos(50, 0)
        phil.seth(180)
        phil.shape(runner)

        #Refer back to first turtle
        def fdp():
            phil.seth(90)
            phil.fd(20)
            if phil.xcor() > 280:
                phil.setx(280)
            if phil.ycor() > 280:
                phil.sety(280)

            if phil.xcor() < -280:
                phil.setx(-280)
            if phil.ycor() < -280:
                phil.sety(-280)
            if isCollision(bob, phil):
                bob.setposition(-50, 0)
                phil.setposition(50, 0)
                bob.seth(0)
                phil.seth(180)
        def rightp():
            phil.seth(0)
            phil.fd(20)
            # Border Checking
            if phil.xcor() > 280:
                phil.setx(280)
            if phil.ycor() > 280:
                phil.sety(280)

            if phil.xcor() < -280:
                phil.setx(-280)
            if phil.ycor() < -280:
                phil.sety(-280)
            # Checks for collision with enemy player
            if isCollision(phil, bob):
                # If there is collision, resets players'
                bob.setposition(-50, 0)
                phil.setposition(50, 0)
                bob.seth(0)
                phil.seth(180)


        def leftp():
            phil.seth(180)
            phil.fd(20)
            # Border Checking
            if phil.xcor() > 280:
                phil.setx(280)
            if phil.ycor() > 280:
                phil.sety(280)

            if phil.xcor() < -280:
                phil.setx(-280)
            if phil.ycor() < -280:
                phil.sety(-280)
            # Checks for collision with enemy player
            if isCollision(phil, bob):
                # If there is collision, resets players'
                bob.setposition(-50, 0)
                phil.setposition(50, 0)
                bob.seth(0)
                phil.seth(180)

        def downp():
            phil.seth(270)
            phil.fd(20)
            # Border Checking
            if phil.xcor() > 280:
                phil.setx(280)
            if phil.ycor() > 280:
                phil.sety(280)

            if phil.xcor() < -280:
                phil.setx(-280)
            if phil.ycor() < -280:
                phil.sety(-280)
            # Checks for collision with enemy player
            if isCollision(phil, bob):
                # If there is collision, resets players'
                bob.setposition(-50, 0)
                phil.setposition(50, 0)
                bob.seth(0)
                phil.seth(180)

        wn.listen()
        wn.onkey(leftp, "a")
        wn.onkey(fdp, "w")
        wn.onkey(rightp, "d")
        wn.onkey(downp, "s")





# Just a start screen
start = turtle.Turtle()
start.speed(0)
start.color("white")
start.penup()
start.goto(0, 0)
start.write("PRESS SPACE TO START!", False, align='center', font=('Arial Bold', 48, 'normal'))
start.hideturtle()

wn.listen()
wn.onkey(game, "space")

# Stops the program from closing automatically when it is run

turtle.done()
```

Along with the actual timer, I would like to actually display the timer in text at the top of the screen, but I'm fairly confident I'll be bale to pull it off when I can actually add the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the package you're using to create the game but I've found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461439/i-want-to-add-a-countdown-timer-to-my-program) that in the answers states there is a `ontimer()` function in turtle.

Of particular interest is this part:

```
def countdown():
    global timer

    timer -= 1

    if timer <= 0:  # time is up, disable user control
        wn.onkey(None, 'Left')
        wn.onkey(None, 'Right')
        wn.onkey(None, 'Up')
        wn.onkey(None, 'Down')
        # Whatever else you need to do to tell the user its game over
    else:
        wn.ontimer(countdown, 1000)  # one second from now

wn.ontimer(countdown, 1000) # start the timer
```

So the function just calls itself after a set amount of milliseconds (1000, aka 1 second in this case), and if its at zero disables controls (customise to your game's needs).

You could set the timer to be 100 ms instead and change the `timer -= 1` to `-= 0.1` for a more granular clock for display purposes.

just remember to create a timer somewhere that's global.

Comment: The global `timer` variable needs to be given an initial value somewhere...

Comment: So what you said works perfectly and looks great when displayed, but when I wanted to make a more granular clock, instead of having the time go down by one decimal place when I displayed it on my screen, there were at least 8 decimal places. It looked like this http://prntscr.com/nkhkrt. And like this when I put it beside text http://prntscr.com/nkhl6w. Is this anyway to negate this?

Comment: @Olympias rounding point errors lead to that unfortunately. However you can limit the number of decimal places displayed. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points/6539677](Try this question for some answers on formatting numbers, its a pain, though the round() function may also work, nowadays, it was janky in the past)